# Como alterar o href de um link de forma dinâmica?

Tags: javascript, html, css

O código no final do enunciado está OK e funciona como esperado.

Nas linhas

```
<a href='?f=on' onclick="alert('LiGHT ON')" class='btn1 btn-sea'>ON</a>
<a href='?f=off' onclick="alert('LiGHT OFF')" class='btn2 btn-sea'>OFF</a>
```

A expressão: `href='?f=xxx'` passa o parâmetro que é preciso para o sistema funcionar. Isto quer dizer que existem 2 botões, um para cada diferente valor do parâmetro.

Eu gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa, porém, utilizando apenas um botão para realizar um evento de cada vez. Algo parecido com o botão *toggle*.

Também é importante manter o uso de HTML/CSS/JavaScript e não usar links ou chamadas para rotinas externas, pois este código ficará embarcado.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='max-age=0' />
  <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache' />
  <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0' />
  <meta http-equiv='expires' content='Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT' />
  <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache' />

  <title>automation</title>

  <style>
   body {font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(85,85,85);} /* backgroud color */
   h1 {font-size: 24px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0.4em 0;}
   .container {width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}
   .container .row {float: left; clear: both; width: 100%;}
   .container .col {float: left; margin: 0 0 1.2em; padding-right: 1.2em; padding-left: 1.2em;}
   .container .col.twelve {width: 100%;}
   @media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
   .container {width: 50%; max-width: 1080px; margin: 0 auto;}
   .container .row {width: 100%; float: left; clear: both;}
   .container .col {float: left; margin: 0 0 1em; padding-right: .5em; padding-left: .5em;}
   .container .col.four {width: 50%;}
   .container .col.tweleve {width: 100%;}}
   * {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
   a {text-decoration: none;}

   .btn1 {font-size: 20px;
          white-space: nowrap;
          width: 100%;
          padding: .8em 1.5em;
          font-family: Helvetica;
          line-height: 20px;
          display: inline-block;
          zoom: 1;
          color: rgb(255,255,255);
          text-align: center;
          position:relative;
          -webkit-transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
          transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;}
   .btn1.btn-sea{background-color: rgb(15,219,0); border-color: rgb(10,145,0); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgb(10,145,0); box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgb(10,145,0);}
   .btn1.btn-sea: hover{background-color: rgb(10,145,0);} 
   .btn1.btn-sea: active{top: 3px; outline: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;}

   .btn2 {font-size: 20px;
          white-space: nowrap;
          width: 100%;
          padding: .8em 1.5em;
          font-family: Helvetica;
          line-height: 20px;
          display: inline-block;
          zoom: 1;
          color: rgb(255,255,255);
          text-align: center;
          position:relative;
          -webkit-transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
          transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;}
   .btn2.btn-sea{background-color: rgb(255,42,42); border-color: rgb(204,0,0); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgb(204,0,0); box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgb(204,0,0);}
   .btn2.btn-sea: hover{background-color: rgb(204,0,0;} 
   .btn2.btn-sea: active{top: 3px; outline: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;}

  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class='container'> 
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col twelve'>
   <p align='center'>
    <font size='10'>REMOTE CONTROL</font>
   </p>
  </div> </div>
   <div class='row'>
   <div class='col four'>
    <a href='?f=on' onclick="alert('LiGHT ON')" class='btn1 btn-sea'>ON</a>
   </div>
   <div class='col four'>
    <a href='?f=off' onclick="alert('LiGHT OFF')" class='btn2 btn-sea'>OFF</a>
   </div> </div>
    <div class='col twelve'> </div> </div>

 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: obrigado pelas correcoes Daniel.

Comment: Você necessitará, no mínimo, de JavaScript para isso. Apenas com HTML e CSS não conseguirá fazer. O quer dizer com "*não usar links ou chamadas para rotinas externas*"? Essa página será embarcada em algum dispositivo e não pode fazer requisições a outros arquivos? É isso?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, muito obrigado pelo seu feedback... ok, podemos usar o javascript tambem, porem ele tem que fazer parte do corpo do programa. Sim, ele nao podera utilizer auxilio externo, por isso eu preciso de uma solucao que esteja completa no mesmo codigo.

Comment: E qual deve ser o botão inicial? *On* ou * Off*? A informação se a página será embarcada em algum dispositivo pode ser importante para este problema. Será?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, obrigado novamente... eu respondi anteriormente... deve ter acontecido alguma demora pra voce vizualizar minha resposta... a resposta eh SIM, sera embarcado... Pode ser inicialmente em OFF... muito obrigado.

Comment: Última pergunta: no que interfere este parâmetro? A página será servida por um código em C que verificará o valor do parâmetro, ligando ou desligando a lâmpada?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, pode fazer quantas perguntas voce achar necessarias... SIM, o codigo discutido aqui, sera implementado em uma rotina em C, para ser um servidor web e quando o codigo retorna, o parametro em questao, servira para que a rotina em C determine o novo status da lampada... como eu expliquei antes, o codigo que eu coloquei aqui, funciona perfeitamente, apenas gostaria que fosse utilizado um botao e nao 2 como eh atualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas informações são triviais para entender o problema e foram passadas nos comentários da pergunta:

- A página será servida por um código em C embarcado em algum dispositivo eletrônico. Isso implica que existe a possibilidade do cliente e servidor não possuírem conexão com a internet para depender de arquivos servidos por um CDN e que o tamanho da página é extremamente sensível, não podendo utilizar bibliotecas de terceiros (jQuery), que aumentam consideravelmente o *payload* da aplicação;
- Sendo a página servida por um código em C, uma requisição *GET* **deve** ser realizada ao pressionar o botão, caso contrário o servidor nunca será notificado da alteração do parâmetro.

Dito isso, podemos resolver o problema utilizando JavaScript (*Vanilla*). Como comentado pelo autor da pergunta, o estado inicial do botão pode ser *OFF*. Sendo assim, definimos o botão no HTML:

```
<a id="btn" href='?f=off' onclick="alert('LiGHT OFF')" class='btn2 btn-sea'>OFF</a>
```

É exatamente o código apresentado na pergunta com a adição do atributo `id`, que será necessário para trabalharmos com o JavaScript. A lógica será a seguinte: ao carregar a página, o JavaScript irá verificar se um parâmetro `?f` foi passado pela URL; se não foi, o código do botão acima permanecerá inalterado, mas se foi passado, o valor de `href` e o texto do botão serão definidos conforme o valor em `?f`. Isto é, se `?f=on`, então o botão a ser exibido deverá ser o *OFF*, porém se `?f=off`, então o botão a ser exibido será o *ON*.

Primeiro, obtemos a URL atual da página:

```
const url = window.location.href;
```

Os valores de `url` serão, dependendo da situação:

```
http://0.0.0.0/index.html
http://0.0.0.0/index.html?f=on
http://0.0.0.0/index.html?f=off
```

Como são apenas esses valores possíveis, podemos extrair o valor de `f` com uma expressão regular simples:

```
/\?f=(on|off)/
```

Assim, se fizermos:

```
const match = url.match(/\?f=(on|off)/);
```

O valor de `match` será `null` quando o valor de `?f` não for especificado, ou um *array*, que na posição 1 haverá o valor `on` ou `off`, dependendo de qual foi especificado. Assim, fazemos:

```
// Verifica se o parâmetro existe:
if (match != null) {

    // Verifica se o valor de ?f é OFF:
    if (match[1] == "off") {

        // Sim, então deverá exibir o botão ON:
        const button = document.getElementById("btn");

        // Altera a URL do botão para ON:
        button.setAttribute("href", "?f=on");

        // Altera o texto do botão:
        button.innerHTML = "ON";

        // Altera a classe do botão para `btn1`:
        button.className = "btn1 btn-sea";

        // Altera o evento `click` do botão para exibir a mensagem "light ON":
        button.onclick = function () {
            alert("Light ON");
        };

    }

}
```

Assim, quando for acessado `?f=off`, o botão será alterado para o *ON*, caso contrário, nada acontecerá e o botão *OFF*, original, permanecerá na página.

Para inserir esse código na página, basta inserí-lo entre as *tags* `script`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const url = window.location.href;
    const match = url.match(/\?f=(on|off)/);

    // Verifica se o parâmetro existe:
    if (match != null) {

        // Verifica se o valor de ?f é OFF:
        if (match[1] == "off") {

            // Sim, então deverá exibir o botão ON:
            const button = document.getElementById("btn");

            button.setAttribute("href", "?f=on");
            button.innerHTML = "ON";

            button.className = "btn1 btn-sea";

            button.onclick = function () {
                alert("Light ON");
            };

        }

    }
</script>
```

> Veja a página funcionando no [JSBin](https://output.jsbin.com/tipureg).

Comment: a principio, não funcionou... depois que eu adicionei as seguintes modificações:   `<script type="text/javascript">

function changeStatus (el) {`

Comment: O que seria essa função `changeStatus`? Tem alguma relação com a outra resposta?

Comment: tive problemas durante a edicao anterior.... a principio, não funcionou... depois que eu adicionei as seguintes modificações:   `<script type="text/javascript">

function changeStatus (el) {`  e  `<a id="btn" href='?f=off' onclick="changeStatus(this)" class='btn2 btn-sea'>OFF</a>` passou a funcionar a alternacia dos parâmetros, que antes ficava sempre em `?f=off`, porem, o botão não alterna a sua aparência entre ON e OFF

Comment: Mas esse não foi o código que eu passei. Como utilizou o código da minha resposta? Coloque no https://jsbin.com.

Comment: esta tudo funcionando corretamente... inicialmente, eu coloquei o script em local errado, por isso que nao deu certo antes. agora eu preciso acertar o C junto com o HTML, para o cliente saber o estado em que se enconta essa saida... mas isso nao faz parte do scope aqui!! muito obrigado pela ajuda @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Essa parte do C não deve ser tão difícil. Qualquer coisa, sinta-se a vontade para abrir uma nova pergunta sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma solução

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
}


/* backgroud color */

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .row {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .col {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 1.2em;
  padding-right: 1.2em;
  padding-left: 1.2em;
}

.container .col.twelve {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  .container {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .container .row {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
  }
  .container .col {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding-right: .5em;
    padding-left: .5em;
  }
  .container .col.four {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .container .col.tweleve {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btnOn {
  font-size: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .8em 1.5em;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
  transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
}

.btnOn.btn-sea {
  background-color: rgb(15, 219, 0);
  border-color: rgb(10, 145, 0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgb(10, 145, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgb(10, 145, 0);
}

.btnOn.btn-sea: hover {
  background-color: rgb(10, 145, 0);
}

.btnOn.btn-sea: active {
  top: 3px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btnOff {
  font-size: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .8em 1.5em;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
  transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
}

.btnOff.btn-sea {
  background-color: rgb(255, 42, 42);
  border-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgb(204, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgb(204, 0, 0);
}

.btnOff.btn-sea: hover {
  background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0;
}

.btnOff.btn-sea: active {
  top: 3px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeStatus (el) {
  var isOn = el.innerHTML == "ON";
  el.className = 'btn-sea ' + (isOn ? "btnOff" :  "btnOn");
  el.innerHTML = isOn ? "OFF" : "ON";
}
</script>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col twelve'>
      <p align='center'>
        <font size='10'>REMOTE CONTROL</font>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col four'>
      <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="changeStatus(this)" class='btnOn btn-sea'>ON</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col twelve'> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: desculpe me colega, mas eu expliquei que nao pode ter links para uso externo. com o uso do ajax, eu tambem sei fazer... tem que mantar apenas o HTML e o CSS nativamente, sem chamadas externas!!! ate pode utilizer esse script externo, se for possivel coloca-lo junto do restante!

Comment: @songa codigo atualizado

Comment: agora a visualizacao esta perfeita, porem o paramentro nao eh passado, como acontece no meu codigo, quado se clica em:      <a href='?f=off'   ou       <a href='?f=on'